# How to find a free TCP port

Tags: linux, tcp, port, netstat

How do I find a completely free TCP port on a server?  I have tried the command line;

```
netstat -an
```

but I am told the ones with a status of LISTENING are already being used.

I also tried a tool called TCPView but again it only showed which TCP ports were being used.  I know how to telnet to a port to check its open but I need to find one that is free.

Comment: AJF : Did you tried it?

Comment: @user3560140 Yes.  Your command simply shows a list of parameter options and I tried a few.  They show TCP ports LISTENING but I believe that is already being used and cannot see a free port.  Would the status of a free port be "FREE" or "OPEN" or what?

Comment: Add -p to that,it will show the process that opened the port:
`netstat -antup`,whatever is not in use is FREE :)

Comment: @user3560140 Thanks for further feedback.  I tried netstat -antup and netstat -lntup and both just provided a list of parameter options as before.  So I tried netstat -antp and it stated "Active Connections" and an empty list with the column headings of "Proto", "Local Address", "Foreign Address", "State" and "Off Load State".  But as I said it listed no connections

Comment: For what purpose? If you just want to listen on an arbitrary port, bind to port 0 and use `getsockname()` to find out what port the OS gave you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`netstat -lntu`

This will solve your purpose.

Comment: This command will list open network ports and the processes that own them. Visit : https://superuser.com/a/529831/881022

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by https://gist.github.com/lusentis/8453523

Start with a seed port, and increment it till it is usable

```
BASE_PORT=16998
INCREMENT=1

port=$BASE_PORT
isfree=$(netstat -taln | grep $port)

while [[ -n "$isfree" ]]; do
    port=$[port+INCREMENT]
    isfree=$(netstat -taln | grep $port)
done

echo "Usable Port: $port"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Bash you can write simple `for` loop to check which TCP ports are free, e.g.

```
$ for i in {1..1024}; do (exec 2>&-; echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/$i && echo $i is open); done
22 is open
25 is open
111 is open
587 is open
631 is open
841 is open
847 is open
1017 is open
1021 is open
```

For more info, check: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 29. `/dev` and `/proc`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html)

Comment: Should this work on mac? It completed without returning any output for me

Comment: this shows the opposite to me: just the busy ones

Answer (score -1):

Building on the answer by @Fengzmg:

This implementation:

- uses the newer `ss` instead of `netstat`
- doesn't rely on `grep`-ing the output, instead we use the filter interface in `ss`
- is more robust because:

  - we only match the source port (`sport`), instead of the `grep` approach that would match destination ports
  - better support for ports that have fewer than 5 digits as we won't match substrings. The `grep` approach would match `443` in `30443`.

Note: the `-4` restricts to *only* IPv4. There's also `-6` but you can not specify either to match on both.

```
BASE_PORT=1234
INCREMENT=1

port=$BASE_PORT

while [ -n "$(ss -tan4H "sport = $port")" ]; do
  port=$((port+INCREMENT))
done

echo "Usable Port: $port"
```